# Daydream (automated testing script writer) skipping random clicks, why is this?

Tags: automated-tests

Daydream is a chrome extension (by `/segmentio` on github) that records your actions into a Nightmare (automated testing) script.

I'm trying to create a tutorial for how to use it but it is not producing a consistent/accurate script when I repeat a simple user journey. Some actions are being missed from the end script in some instances and then being recorded successfully on another occasion.

This is the issue documenting my exploration on github: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-daydream-and-nightmare/issues/8

Initially I recognised the issue when navigating to a new tab in a test and so I commented on an existing issue on the subject on Segment's repo: https://github.com/segmentio/daydream/issues/31
The issue was first raised by another user in September 2016 and has not received any response so I think it's unlikely they will respond.

**- Has anyone come across this problem using Daydream? and did you find a solution?**

**- Is there a specific action which may be causing this bug?**

**- Can anyone see any issues in the segmentio code that could be causing this?**

Thanks :)